VS Code Deletes the First Character of the File Name
while working on a web project on the server in the VS Code program, it automatically deletes the first character of the file name when trying to upload the file I edited with the sftp plugin (regardless of extensions) to the server.
For example; After processing the database.php file, after uploading it to the server, I display it on the server as atabase.php.
If the file I want to upload is in a folder, it deletes the first character of the folder name.
File directory I want to upload: public_html->config->app.php
the wrong directory on the server after upload: ublic_html->config->app.php[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/BUsMsHzu.jpg)
I checked my sftp plugin settings.
I completed my VS Code updates.
I can upload on a different computer with the same sftp settings without any problems.
The problem is not on the server.

"I can upload on a different computer with the same sftp settings without any problems."  So you can upload from a different local machine to the same remove server and it works as expected? Did you check you have the same version of the SFTP plugin on both machines? Are both machines running the same OS? ie it might be a problem of the plugin with wrongly interpreted path separators? But this seems to be an issue with the plugin. You could try raise an issue in its source repository.

And just to be clear: The filename is changed locally and remote?

Everything is the same on both computers. We can change the file name locally and on the remote server. Creating a different user account on the computer where we had the problem and reinstalling vs code on that user solved the problem. We still can't figure out exactly why it happened.
